# How to update tree view control values into database in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table on database something like below

[image]

where the subcategories populate into `treeview` with column `SubcatID` like

[image]

When i update my values with check the nodes and its updated perfectly and i am use the code as below

```
 foreach (TreeNode node in tvCategories.Nodes)
            {
                // get the child nodes 
                TreeNodeCollection childNodes = node.ChildNodes;
                // iterate through the child nodes 
                foreach (TreeNode childNode in childNodes)
                {
                    if (childNode.Checked)
                    {
                        int val = int.Parse(childNode.Value);
                        conn.Open();
                        string query1 = "UpdatePhotographyCategory";
                        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query1, conn);
                        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subcatid", val);
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContributorID", this.ContributerID);
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationId", Dllscity.SelectedValue);
                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Now my question is that when i uncheck the values which is inserted into database already . how to update or delete that values. please help me for this issue .

Comment: simply in `else {}` delete unchecked values

Comment: and how i get the unchecked values ??

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
 foreach (TreeNode childNode in tvCategories.Nodes)
            {
                foreach (TreeNode child in childNode.ChildNodes)
                {
                    string aa = child.Value;
                    if (child.Checked == true)
                    {
                        Label1.Text += "Checked Node :" + child.Value + " <br />";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Label1.Text += "UnChecked Node :" + child.Value + " <br />";
                    }
                }


            }
```

Comment: and what is the values for delete. i mean how i get the unchecked values?

Comment: using this `int val = int.Parse(childNode.Value);`

Comment: no its wrong it is delete all values which is selected or unselected both :(

Comment: @GarimaRawat i tried and test on my pc now its works

Comment: i have also try it but it's deleted all the values which is selected or unselected.

Comment: first of all check whether you are getting right results in Labels or not? it should display which are checked and which are unchecked as i did